# How to reset ant design table selected rows?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

- I am using `ant design table` component and I have selected rows.
- I want `onClick` reset selected rows.
- I can not find out where it stores selected rows.

  ```
    const rowSelection = {
          onChange: (selectedRowKeys, rows) => {
            this.setState({
              selectedRowsArray: [...rows]
            });
          },
        };

    <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={paymentsHistory} />
  ```

Any Idea how to clear selected `rows`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`rowSelection` also takes `selectedRowKeys` property that will help you control the selected rows at any point in time.

```
const { selectedRowsArray } = this.state;
const rowSelection = {
      selectedRowKeys: selectedRowsArray,
      onChange: (selectedRowKeys, rows) => {
        this.setState({
          selectedRowsArray: [...rows]
        });
      },
    };

<Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={paymentsHistory} />
```

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3vkoz28xo5) | [Antd Docs](https://ant.design/components/table/#rowSelection)

Comment: what if selectedRowsArray is an array of object, will this work the same way?

Comment: not sure what you mean here, `selectedRowKeys` is an argument to the table, it has to be string or number array

Comment: please note that selectedRowKeys keeps the old state if received undefined

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this with hooks:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'antd';

function App() {
    const [selectedRowKeys, setRowKeys] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState([]);


    const start = () => {
        setRowKeys([]);
    };

    const onSelectChange = selectedRowKeys => {
        setRowKeys(selectedRowKeys);
    };

    const rowSelection = {
        selectedRowKeys,
        onChange: onSelectChange,
    };

    const dataSource = [
        {
            key: '1',
            name: 'Mike',
            age: 32,
            address: '10 Downing Street',
        },
        {
            key: '2',
            name: 'John',
            age: 42,
            address: '10 Downing Street',
        }, enter code here
    ];

    const columns = [
        {
            title: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            key: 'name',
        },
        {
            title: 'Age',
            dataIndex: 'age',
            key: 'age',
        },
        {
            title: 'Address',
            dataIndex: 'address',
            key: 'address',
        },
    ];


    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Button type="primary" onClick={start} >
                Reload
            </Button>
            <Table dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} rowSelection={rowSelection} />;
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe following example will make it clear for you:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Table, Button } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";

export default function App() {
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Currency",
      dataIndex: "сurrency",
      key: "сurrency"
    }
  ];
  const data = [
    {
      key: "EUR",
      сurrency: "€"
    },
    {
      key: "USD",
      сurrency: "$"
    },
    {
      key: "RUB",
      сurrency: "₽"
    }
  ];

  const [selectedRowsArray, setSelectedRowsArray] = useState([]);
  const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys: selectedRowsArray,
    onChange: (key) => {
      setSelectedRowsArray(key);
      exchangeMoney(key[0]);
    }
  };

  function exchangeMoney(key) {
    console.log(key);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
        rowSelection={{ type: "radio", ...rowSelection }}
      />
      <Button className="clear-btn" onClick={() => setSelectedRowsArray([])}>
        CLEAR
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[see in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-sutherland-m7zojb?file=/src/App.js:0-1012)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.